# How to link a doxygen documentation in html to another one?

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to link two doxygen html documentations. To this end, I generated the first documentation for package A using GENERATE_TAGFILE, then I set in the Doxyfile of package B TAGFILES = "pathtotagfile = relpathtodocumentation". This seems to work properly, since there are no warnings. However, I the connection of the two packages is not as deep as I would like it to be.

Using doxygen 1.8.13, I only see links to the external files. Can I configure that classes and namespaces also list external stuff? I have set ALLEXTERNALS, EXTERNAL_GROUPS and EXTERNAL_PAGES to YES, but still I only see external files.

Using doxygen 1.8.4, external packages appear under Related Pages, but this seems to have been [changed](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/commit/a2c7f91d6320f72951f1e3ef092e077a89562670). I would have appreciated this. Can I reenable it in the latest version?

I also welcome hints at how Link to external documentation works. The [doxygen help](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/external.html) is a bit short here.

Comment: Maybe the ALLEXTERNALS option is broken. I am currently trying the same thing. I managed to make the links to the external documentation work, but the class index does not contain the external classes as the documentation of the ALLEXTERNALS option states.

Comment: There is a bug (since 2009) that the ALLEXTERNALS = YES option will not cause external classes to be included in the class index. https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=597928

Comment: Looks like this has been moved from bugzilla to a github list of open issues: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/3557 It is still listed as open there.